Why is the type of an entire function with growth order 1 and integer derivatives at z = 0 greater than or equal to 1?
Let  $f(z)$  be an entire function such that:

$f(z)$  has growth order  $\rho_f = 1$ , i.e., $\rho_f = \limsup_{r \to \infty} \frac{\log \log M(r)}{\log r} = 1$, where  $M(r) = \max_{|z| = r} |f(z)| $.

$f^{(n)}(0) \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall  n \in \mathbb{N}$.


I would like to understand why these conditions imply that the type $\sigma_f$  of  $f(z)$ , defined as:
$\sigma_f = \limsup_{r \to \infty} \frac{\log M(r)}{r}$, must satisfy  $\sigma_f \geq 1$.
Is there a formal proof or intuitive reasoning that connects the integer nature of the coefficients to the growth type of the function?

The answer comes from the fact that there is a formula for the type that depends only on the $\limsup$ of an expression in the Taylor coefficients that is increasing for each fixed $n$ and is "regular" for the Taylor coefficients of the exponential (in the sense that there it is an actual limit not only a $\limsup$).
In other words for a fixed order $\rho$ there is a set of increasing functions $h_{n, \rho}$ (meaning that for a fixed $n, h_{n, \rho}$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$) st if $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ is entire of order $\rho$ we have $$\sigma_f=\limsup_n h_{n,\rho}(|a_n|)$$ and $\limsup_n h_{n,1}(1/n!)=\lim_n h_{n,1}(1/n!)$
Here $h_{n, \rho}(x)=\frac{nx^{\rho/n}}{\rho e}, x \ge 0$ so $h_{n,1}=\frac{nx^{1/n}}{ e}$ and the regularity condition mentioned is obvious (by Stirling) but the actual formula for the function is somewhat immaterial for the purposes of this question,
Now the integer conditions on the derivative mean that $|a_n|=\frac{q_n}{n!}$ with $q_n \ge 0$ integer and infinitely many $q_n \ge 1$ since $f$ is not a polynomial. In particular for the  subsequence of nonzero $q_n$ we have $h_{n,1}(q_n/n!) \ge h_{n,1}(1/n!)$ so taking the $\limsup$ we get that $\sigma_f \ge \sigma_{e^z}=1$
Note that the same reasoning applied to the formula for the order shows that an entire transcendental (not a polynomial) function with integer derivatives of any order at zero must have order at least $1$.

$\sigma_f = \limsup_{n \to \infty} h_{n,\rho}(|a_n|).$
I understand that this formula is said to hold for entire functions, but why is it valid? Specifically: What is the reasoning behind the definition of  h_{n,\rho} , and how is it connected to the type of the function?

Oh, I understood. Thank you!
